# open layers 2.12 select feature control "over" callback triggered twice

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using [Open Layers (v2.12)](http://openlayers.org/), and am trying to use the [SelectFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.selectStyle).

I have managed to get things working, but with an interesting behavior, the "over" callback seems to be triggered twice. This isn't good because I want to display a tooltip when the user hovers over a polygon. If I used my code as is, it would add the tooltip twice, which will look flickery at best.

UPDATE: I've also just realised that the "over" callback overrides the "selectStyle" highlight, that's an issue, I've removed the over callback for now until I get a better solution.

Here is the select feature code snippet...

```
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
    hover: true,
    toggle: true,
    selectStyle: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        strokeColor: "#ffffff",
        cursor: "pointer"
    },
    callbacks: {
        click: function(event){
            console.log("clicked");
        },
        over: function(event){
            console.log("mouse over");
        }
    }
})

map.addControl(selectControl);

selectControl.activate();
```

To get this working you'll need to create a map and the vector layer, which I could add if someone really needs it all.

So in summary, I need to work out how to stop the "over" callback from triggering more than once.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's some weird openlayers bug. Happened to me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way I have discovered that will do what I want, but it seems a bit horrible becasue it uses a second syntax for adding callbacks, and I dont see why there would be more than one way of adding handlers to a layer. Hopefully this will be picked up in the next version.

here is my code with amendment for mouse over handler...

```
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
    hover: true,
    toggle: true,
    selectStyle: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        strokeColor: "#ffffff",
        cursor: "pointer"
    },
    callbacks: {
        click: function(event){
            console.log("clicked");
        }
        //removed 'over' callback
    },
    //here is the extra handler.
    eventListeners: {
        featurehighlighted: function(event){
            console.log("mouse over");
        }
    }
})

map.addControl(selectControl);

selectControl.activate();
```

So this is only triggered once, but as you can see, it has 2 variants for adding mouse event type handlers.

I don't want to tick this as my answer because it doesn't seem like a great solution.

UPDATE: well no one has come up with an alternative so I guess I'm forced to accept my own answer, never mind.